# Find index of row from df for which |df$col1-df2$col1| = min|dist|. Then find max value of col2 from df in the range [idx-5;idx+5]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` has two columns. I'd like to find the index `idx` of `row` from `df1`, that contains in `col1` the minimum distance from the value of `df2 col1`.

Next, I want to find the max value of `df1 col2` from `neighborhood [idx-10, idx+10]`. Then attach that value to `df2` to corresponding row for which the min distance was found.

Here is an example of the two data frames:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1.5,2.5,3,3.5,3.95,4.55,5.1, 5.54, 6.02, 6.57], 
"B": [0.25, 0.6, 1.34, 0.75, 0.16, 1.04, 0.99, 0.23, 0.95, 0.65,0.22]})
       A     B
0   1.00  0.25
1   1.50  0.60
2   2.50  1.34
3   3.00  0.75
4   3.50  0.16
5   3.95  1.04
6   4.55  0.99
7   5.10  0.23
8   5.54  0.95
9   6.02  0.65
10  6.57  0.22



df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1.06, 2.34, 3.70, 6, 7.2], "C": ["pink", "blue", "orange", "pink", "orange"]})



      A1       C
0  1.06    pink
1  2.34    blue
2  3.70  orange
3  6.00    pink
4  7.20  orange
```

For the convenience sake, I'll choose the interval `[idx-2;idx+2]`. Here is the desired result:

```
  df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A1":[1.06,2.34, 3.70, 6, 7.2], "B": [1.34, 1.34, 1.04, 0.95, 0.95], "C": ["pink", "blue", "orange",
"pink", "orange"]})
   
     A1     B       C
0  1.06  1.34    pink
1  2.34  1.34    blue
2  3.70  1.04  orange
3  6.00  0.95    pink
4  7.20  0.95  orange
```

I know that I could merge these data frames, but the problem is that one of them, `df1`, is very large, so it would take ridiculous amount of memory to compute all possible distances of columns `A` and `A1`. So, maybe there is something more efficient than that?

Comment: @Zero The value of minimum distance from A1==1.06 is A=1. So the idx==0. Then in the interval [0;2] max value of B is equal to 1.34.

Comment: So you want the minimum distance for each row? Or for the whole thing?

Comment: @Zero I added more detailed example, so it should be clearer now. In short, I need to find the max value of B within a range [idx-2;idx+2], where idx is the row index of df1 for which the A1[i]-A[j] is the most minimal. Then add that max B value to the i-th row of df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df1` is already sorted on column `A`, Lets use `searchsorted` to get the indices of closest values in `A` corresponding to the values from `A1` , then make sure to clip the indices where the index value equal to length of `df1`. Now, do a centered rolling max on `df1.B`, finally use the closest indices to get the corresponding maximum values within a interval

```
i = np.searchsorted(df1['A'], df2['A1'], side='right')
i[i == len(df1)] -= 1

w = 2
r = df1['B'].rolling(2 * w + 1, center=True, min_periods=1).max()
df2['B'] = r.iloc[i].tolist()
```

---

```
     A1       C     B
0  1.06    pink  1.34
1  2.34    blue  1.34
2  3.70  orange  1.04
3  6.00    pink  0.95
4  7.20  orange  0.95
```